# "no such file or directory" in preloader

Tags: coronasdk

I'm making a preloader for a large application. Today the error occurred "no such file or directory". This error occurs only on Android device. On the computer(in the simulator) works fine. All file names and directories to lowercase.

Code:

```
---------------------------------------------
---------------- Прелоадер ------------------
-- Сервис по загрузке текстур, звука --------
---------------------------------------------

TEXTURES = {} -- место в оперативной памяти для текстур
SOUNDS = {} -- место в оперативной памяти для звука

local Preloader = {}
local path = {
    animations = "assets/images/animations/",
    army_run = "assets/images/animations/army_run/",
    area = "assets/images/area/",
    access = "assets/images/area/access/",
    artefacts = "assets/images/artefacts/",
    castles = "assets/images/building/castles/",
    mining = "assets/images/building/mining/",
    flags = "assets/images/flags/",
    interface = "assets/images/interface/",
    marker = "assets/images/interface/marker/",
    items = "assets/images/items/",
    raw = "assets/images/raw/",
}

-- Место для путей к текстурам
Preloader.texture = {}

-- Место для путей к звуку
Preloader.sound = {}

-- Загрузка текстур в оперативную память
Preloader.loadingTextures = function(arr)
    TEXTURES[arr.id] = {}
    for i = 1, #arr do
        local name = string.gsub(arr[i], '.*(.*)/', '')
        TEXTURES[arr.id][name] = graphics.newTexture( { type="image", filename = arr[i] } )
        TEXTURES[arr.id][name]:preload()
    end
end

-- Загрузка звука в оперативную память
Preloader.loadingSounds = function()
    for i = 1, #Preloader.sound do
        sounds[Preloader.sound[i]] = audio.loadSound( "snd/"..Preloader.sound[i] )
    end
end

-- Таймер
Preloader.getTimer = function()
    return system.getTimer()
end

-- Окно загрузки
Preloader.screenLoader = nil
Preloader.loaderShow = function()
    if(Preloader.screenLoader)then
        return false
    end 

    Preloader.screenLoader = display.newGroup()
    Preloader.screenLoader.x = _W/2
    Preloader.screenLoader.y = _H/2

    local screen = display.newRect( 0, 0, _W, _H )
    screen:setFillColor( 0, 0, 0 )
    Preloader.screenLoader:insert(screen)

    local imgLoad = "assets/images/animations/army_run/150.png"
    local sheetLoad = graphics.newImageSheet( imgLoad, { width = 224, height = 224, numFrames = 8 } )

    local animLoad = display.newSprite( Preloader.screenLoader, sheetLoad, { start = 1, count = 8, time = 800, loopCount=0 } )
    animLoad.xScale, animLoad.yScale = _H*.001, _H*.001
    animLoad.x, animLoad.y = 0, _H*-.07
    animLoad:play()

    -- Загрузка в процентах
    tfLoader = display.newText( TEXTS.Preloader.loading..": 0%", 0, _H*.08, font, _H*.035 )
    tfLoader:setTextColor( 1,1,1) 
    Preloader.screenLoader:insert(tfLoader)
    Preloader.screenLoader.tf = tfLoader

    -- Загрузка в этапах
    stepLoader = display.newText( TEXTS.Preloader.start_load, 0, _H*.125, font, _H*.022 )
    stepLoader:setTextColor( 160/255, 160/255, 160/255 ) 
    Preloader.screenLoader:insert(stepLoader)
    Preloader.screenLoader.step = stepLoader
end

-- Создание массивов с путями
Preloader.createPath = function()
    for k, v in pairs(path) do
        local i = 0
        Preloader.texture[k] = { id = k }
        for l in lfs.dir(v) do
            if ( l ~= "." and l ~= ".." and l ~= "..." ) then
                i = i + 1
                Preloader.texture[k][i] = v..l
            end
        end
    end
end

-- Запуск прелоадера и контроль процесса загрузки
Preloader.start = function() 
    -- Создаём шаги для загрузки
    local loading_steps = {}

    -- Шаг 1 - Загрузка путей
    table.insert(loading_steps, function()
        Preloader.createPath()
        Preloader.screenLoader.step.text = TEXTS.Preloader.path_load..'...'
    end)

    -- Шаг 2 - Загрузка текстур интерфейса
    table.insert(loading_steps, function()
        Preloader.loadingTextures(Preloader.texture.interface)
        Preloader.loadingTextures(Preloader.texture.marker)
        Preloader.screenLoader.step.text = TEXTS.Preloader.interface_load..'...'
    end)

    -- Шаг 3 - Загрузка анимаций
    table.insert(loading_steps, function()
        Preloader.loadingTextures(Preloader.texture.animations)
        Preloader.loadingTextures(Preloader.texture.army_run)
        Preloader.screenLoader.step.text = TEXTS.Preloader.animations_load..'...'
    end)

    -- Шаг 4 - Создание карты
    table.insert(loading_steps, function()
        Preloader.loadingTextures(Preloader.texture.area)
        Preloader.loadingTextures(Preloader.texture.access)
        Preloader.loadingTextures(Preloader.texture.castles)
        Preloader.loadingTextures(Preloader.texture.mining)
        Preloader.screenLoader.step.text = TEXTS.Preloader.map_load..'...'
    end)

    -- Шаг 5 - Загрузка ресурсов
    table.insert(loading_steps, function()
        Preloader.loadingTextures(Preloader.texture.raw)
        Preloader.loadingTextures(Preloader.texture.items)
        Preloader.loadingTextures(Preloader.texture.artefacts)
        Preloader.screenLoader.step.text = TEXTS.Preloader.res_load..'...'
    end)

    -- Шаг 6 - Загрузка параметров игрока
    table.insert(loading_steps, function()
        Preloader.loadingTextures(Preloader.texture.flags)
        Preloader.screenLoader.step.text = TEXTS.Preloader.res_load..'...'
    end)

    local loading_steps_max = #loading_steps+1
    local st = Preloader.getTimer()
    Preloader.loaderShow()

    local function mainHandler(e)
        if(#loading_steps>0)then
            loading_steps[1]()
            table.remove(loading_steps, 1)

            if(Preloader.screenLoader)then
                local loading_p = math.floor((loading_steps_max - #loading_steps)*100/loading_steps_max)
                Preloader.screenLoader.tf.text = TEXTS.Preloader.loading..': '..loading_p..'%'
            end
            return true
        end
        Preloader.loaderClose()
        print('Time load: '..(Preloader.getTimer()-st)..'ms')

        Runtime:removeEventListener("enterFrame", mainHandler)
    end
    Runtime:addEventListener("enterFrame", mainHandler)
end

-- Окончание загрузки
Preloader.loaderClose = function()
    if(Preloader.screenLoader)then
        if(Preloader.screenLoader.removeSelf)then
            Preloader.screenLoader:removeSelf()
        end
    end
    Preloader.screenLoader = nil

    -- Переход на стартовую сцену
    composer.gotoScene( start_scene, "fade", 0 )
end

-- Сборщик мусора
Preloader.garbage_collector = function()
    for key in pairs(TEXTURES) do
        for i=1, #TEXTURES[key] do
            TEXTURES[key][i]:releaseSelf()
        end
    end
    TEXTURES = {}
end

return Preloader
```

That's how I show images on stage:

```
M.dial = display.newImageRect( M.gr, TEXTURES.interface["btn_compas_comp.png"].filename, TEXTURES.interface["btn_compas_comp.png"].baseDir, 272, 272 )
M.dial.x, M.dial.y = X, Y
```

Thanks in advance friends.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) `All file names and directories to lowercase` - I suggest to double-check this because Android filesystem is case sensitive.

2) Also check your `build.settings` to ensure that `excludeFiles` section doesn't include any of directories from your code

**Edit:** Another idea based on [corona lfs doc](https://docs.coronalabs.com/api/library/lfs/index.html) - try following before loading:

```
local resourcesPath = system.pathForFile( "", system.ResourceDirectory )

-- Change current working directory
local success = lfs.chdir( resourcesPath )  --returns true on success
```

I guess that lfs doesn't point on resource directory by default. All your assets should be in this directory, but don't try to modify them - `For security reasons, this directory is read-only and enforced by the operating system, not by Corona.`

**Edit 2:** Solution that don't rely on current directory

```
Preloader.createPath = function()
  for k, v in pairs(path) do
    local i = 0
    local pathForDirectory = system.pathForFile(v, system.ResourceDirectory)
    Preloader.texture[k] = { id = k }
    for l in lfs.dir(pathForDirectory) do
        if ( l ~= "." and l ~= ".." and l ~= "..." ) then
            i = i + 1
            Preloader.texture[k][i] = v..l
        end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Rechecked a bunch of times. Guesses: maybe the lfs module does not work with the application directory on the device.

Comment: @ВладиславВыпадко see my edited answer - probably `chdir` could help

Comment: I have the next error: "bad argument #1 to 'dir' (string exprcted, got nil)"